# Which is the best hashing function for generating unique key for every nodes of a Tree?

Tags: c, hash, tree, md5, sha256

I have a tree structure. I would like to generate a unique key for each node of the key such that collision is minimal. 
For eg:

```
root -
     |
    (a)--
    |    |
    |   (b)--
    |       |
    |      (a)--(v = 50)
    |
     ----(c)--
          |   |
          |   (b)--(v = "a string")
          |
          |
           ---(a)--(v = 2.45)
```

I need to generate a unique key for every node in the tree hierarchy.

```
            Key strings                hash
-------------------------------------------------
a -                                    ?
a/b                                    ?
a/b/a                                  ?
a/b/a/v=50                             ?
a/c/                                   ?
a/c/b                                  ?
a/c/b/v="a string"                     ?
a/c/a                                  ?
a/c/a/v==2.45                          ?
```

I am planning to use md5 or sh4256 for generating hashes from the key strings. The question is is there a better way than this? I mean an algorithm which can make a key out of string which is unique? 
Or are there any better function than md5 or sha256 considering the application runs on an embedded system with limited computation power?

Comment: And what do you do if you have a collision?

Comment: Which is it – “collision is minimal” or “unique”? That is, is a fast hash that has a somewhat low chance of colliding but *can* collide evenn in practice okay, or are you just looking for the fastest cryptographic hash?

Comment: The only unique key is the string itself. A hash function, be definition, will generate collisions.

Comment: @Ry : Initially, I thought of using the paths string itself. The problem is in the real word application, my paths "a/b/c../" can be huge and want to map it to a 128 or 256 character string. Ideally, the keys should be unique if it collides, I have to add a differant logic to generate a new key.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie _"be [sic] definition, will generate collisions"_: Technically, that's not correct. There are [perfect hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function), too.

Comment: @andreee, I looked it up (thanks). A perfect hash function requires at least as many values (hash buckets) as there are items to be stored. So it generates a unique integer key `0..>=n-1`.

Comment: @IndreLemur SHA-256 seems fine then. (Or something shorter, like SHA-224 or a 128-bit prefix of either of those, depending on the size of your input.)